# Unit testing a repository function and is it even necessary?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I'm struggling with the usefulness of a test I wrote. In fact, I'm not so sure the test I wrote is really the correct thing to do. I have a repository class with the function `where($q, $count)` where 'q' is a query string and count is the number of results I expect back. The function depends on my ORM. I expect to call several functions on the ORM. I am use [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) to mock the dependency on the ORM object. I wrote a test to verify that I am querying on 4 specific fields only. Here is the function followed by the test:

```
public function where($q, $count)
{
    if(is_null($count))
    {
        $count = 100;
    }

    $query = '%'.$q.'%';

    $contracts = $this->contractModel
        ->where('contractNumber', 'like', $query)
        ->orwhere('customerName', 'like', $query)
        ->orWhere('customerId', 'like', $query)
        ->orwhere('contractName', 'like', $query)
        ->paginate($count, [ 'contractNumber', 'contractName', 'revision', 'customerId', 'customerName' ]);

    $this->assignContractAPIUrlToResults($contracts);

    $modifiedPagerResults = $this->queryHelper->setupAdditionalPageOptions($contracts, $count);

    return $modifiedPagerResults;
}

public function it_should_query_different_fields()
{
    $eloquentBuilder = m::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder');
    $queryBuilder = m::mock('Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder');
    $paginator = m::mock('\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator');

    $this->contractModelMock->shouldReceive('where')->once()->with('contractNumber', 'like', '%foo%')->andReturn($eloquentBuilder);
    $eloquentBuilder->shouldReceive('orWhere')->once()->with('customerName', 'like', '%foo%')->andReturn($eloquentBuilder);
    $eloquentBuilder->shouldReceive('orWhere')->once()->with('customerId', 'like', '%foo%')->andReturn($eloquentBuilder);
    $eloquentBuilder->shouldReceive('orWhere')->once()->with('contractName', 'like', '%foo%')->andReturn($queryBuilder);

    $paginationResultContainer = [
        'contractNumber',
        'contractName',
        'revision',
        'customerId',
        'customerName'
    ];

    $queryBuilder->shouldReceive('paginate')->once()->with(5, $paginationResultContainer)->andReturn($paginator);

    $paginator->shouldReceive('getItems')->once()->andReturn([]);

    $this->queryResultHelperMock->shouldReceive('setupAdditionalPageOptions')->once()->with($paginator, 5);

    $this->contractRepository->where('foo', 5);
}
```

Am I doing this wrong? I've read that a unit test should not be testing implementation details, but how else would I test that I specifically want to query on 4 fields and only those 4 fields? Because my function is mostly only calling functions on dependencies, it feels like maybe this function doesn't need to be tested? Using PHPUnit, I'm unable to make the test pass WITHOUT telling the test what functions should be called on the dependencies and what they should return.

Comment: Does the test provide some value to you?  To put it another way, does the value provided by the test exceed the effort you put in to write it?  It sounds more like an integration test than a unit test.  But that doesn't necessarily make it a bad test.

Comment: I guess where I'm stuck is whether or not it is "appropriate" to have implementation details in the test, even though it's related to a dependency. If the dependency I'm using introduced a new function later that did all of these "wheres" in 1 call and I changed my function, my test would fail, even though the result is the same. Should a unit test simply be "given this input, I expect this output"?

Comment: Yes, it probably should.

Comment: Then, in your opinion, what would be a better way to test what I'm trying to test. Mockery will cause the test to fail if I don't tell it that I expect certain functions to be called on a dependency, so it's not like I can just leave that out.

Comment: I looked at your code again, and I think I stand by my original assertions.  If the test is valuable to you as is, I'd leave it alone and get on with life.  If one of your actual software requirements is that the test should not break if you change the implementation, then you'll have to do something else.  I suspect the test is fine the way it is now.